# v3.2.6 of SourceTree for Windows showing ALL closed branches

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I was on v3.2.5 of SourceTree for Windows, working fine without any problem.

Then after upgrading to v3.2.6, my HgFlow-enabled repo is listing ALL the closed branches, ALL the closed features, ALL the closed releases in the treeview on the left!!

There is no way to rollback to v3.2.5, so I re-downloaded SourceTree from the web site, which installed v3.1.3.  The upgrade notification says a new version is available, but the version it says is unavailable is v3.2.6, so I will be sticking to v3.1.3 for now.

Anyone else experiencing this problem in v3.2.6?

Comment: Yep. Issue still seems present in 3.3.6.